# Stroke of some map path is fragmented

Tags: d3.js

I created a map of Europe using two json files.
When the user double-clicks on a country, the country is zoomed and his regions are displayed.

Now I would like that when the user hovers over a country/region, the edge of the corresponding path changes color. It's a very easy thing.
Here is the piece of code that does this thing:

```
mapSvgGCountryPath.attr('class', 'country')
    .attr('fill', 'black')
    .style('stroke', 'white')
    .style('stroke-width', 2) 
    .attr('d', path)
    .attr('id', function(c) {
        return 'country' + c.properties.nuts_id; 
    })
    .on('click', clickOrDoubleCountry)
    .on('mouseover', function(d) {
        d3.select(this).style('stroke', 'red');
    })
    .on('mouseout', function(d) {
        d3.select(this).style('stroke', 'white');
    });
```

The problem is that the result doesn't work:

[image]

The border of some countries is broken (it seems that countries share some pieces of stroke).
Is it due to how the json files are made? [In my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50213603/inaccuracies-on-the-map-using-two-json) I explained how I got these files.

How can I solve?

[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/5a7yc8MRwn5Yb5WKwvUs?preview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no *"countries sharing the stroke"*. The issue here is just that one `<path>` is over the other one.

Just `raise` the country you hover over, to move it to the bottom of the parent's group:

```
.on('mouseover', function(d) {
    d3.select(this).style('stroke', 'red').raise();
})
```

The logic here is that the elements painted last remain on top of the other elements.

Here is the updated Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/R96JM4ZZrAJ8X1YuUWdO?preview&p=preview